# Dynamic Makefile target

Tags: makefile

Here's a snippet of a GNU Makefile I'm working with. Basically, I have a directory of images that i want copied into a dist directory when running make, but I'd prefer not to list each image individually.

```
DISTDIR := dist
IMG := $(shell find app/img -type f)
$(subst app/img, $(DISTDIR), $(filter-out %.svg, $(IMG)))): $(filter-out %.svg, $(IMG))
        @cp $? $(DISTDIR)
```

This sort of works, except any time a source file is changed (in `app/img`), make **always** remakes the target file. What's the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if you provided some sample results for the find.  Let's say that the find operation returns the files: `app/img/foo.svg`, `app/img/bar.jpg`, and `app/img/baz.png`.

In that case the `filter-out` functions will return the files `app/img/bar.jpg` and `app/img/baz.png`.  This means that the rule generated will look like this:

```
$(DISTDIR)/bar.jpg $(DISTDIR)/baz.png: app/img/bar.jpg app/img/baz.png
        @cp $? $(DISTDIR)
```

Here's the thing: when you define N targets in an explicit rule, it's like defining N rules, one for each target, with all the same prerequisites.  So the above is identical to writing this:

```
$(DISTDIR)/bar.jpg: app/img/bar.jpg app/img/baz.png
        @cp $? $(DISTDIR)
$(DISTDIR)/baz.png: app/img/bar.jpg app/img/baz.png
        @cp $? $(DISTDIR)
```

Now you can see why you get the behavior that you do: each target lists *ALL* the files as prerequisites, so whenever *ANY* file is changed the target is rebuilt.

The answer is that in make, you should generally try to write rules that create exactly one target from just that target's prerequisites.  One simple way to do that is with pattern rules; a pattern rule for the above might look like:

```
DISTDIR := dist

$(DISTDIR)/% : app/img/%
    @cp $< $@
```

After that, all you have to do is declare a target which depends on the files you want created:

```
IMG := $(shell find app/img -type f)

all: $(IMG:app/img/%=$(DISTDIR)/%)
```

and make will figure out the rest!